# Solspace Importer Grid field

Tags: matrix, solspace, grid, solspace-importer

Does the Solspace Importer support the new EE Grid field? I didn't see it mentioned anywhere in the documentation, only the Matrix field. If yes - any documentation available?

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, Importer does not import into Grid fields.

I suggest commenting or adding your +1 in our feature request section found here: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/

In particular, this feature request thread seems spot-on: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions/topics/33803